# How to model a Question and Answer data structure in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This feels like it should be super simple, but for the life of me I haven't been able to get it right.

In my application, I want to have `Questions` and `Answers`.

A `Question` can only have 1 `Answer`, but an `Answer` can be used for many `Question`s.

**For example.**

*Question Table Data*

1. "Two plus Two equals?"
2. "Number of sides to a square?"

*Answer Table Data*

1. Four

Both `Question`s only have 1 `Answer`, but the `Answer` record can be used for both `Questions`.

I thought maybe this would work ::

```
rails g resource question verbiage:string answer:references
```

but then I have to put a `belongs_to :answer` on the `Question` model and that doesn't seem right.

It feels like it should be possible to do something like ::

```
Question.first.answer # returns the single answer

Answer.first.questions # returns all of the Questions where this record is the Answer
```

Can anyone educate me on the proper way to model this in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [has_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) assosiaction.
I'm gonna use scaffold for this.

1. Create Answer:

   ```
   rails g scaffold Answer value:string
   ```
2. Create Question:

   ```
   rails g scaffold Question verbiage:string answer:references
   ```
3. Run `rails db:migrate`
4. Create assosiactions.

   ```
   class Answer < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :questions
   end

   class Question < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :answer
   end
   ```

Comment: After I posted, I wondered if maybe a `has_many` was the answer, but it felt really weird to say, "An Answer has many Questions".  It feels like a Question should own an Answer, but maybe I'm getting too caught up in terminology.  Either way, I took your suggestion and it works exactly as I wanted it to.  Thanks a ton @demir !

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use demir's answer of

- question belongs_to answer
- answer has_many question

You'll have to

- Make a QuestionAnswer join table
- QuestionAnswer belongs_to question
- QuestionAnswer belongs_to answer
- question has_one question_answers
- answer has_many question_answers

Then

- question has_one :answer through :question_answer source :answer
- answer has_many :question through :question_answer source :question

Ex. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

> For example, it makes more sense to say that a supplier owns an account than that an account owns a supplier. This suggests that the correct relationships are like this

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what the requirements are. In most cases you actually need a join table:

```
class Question
  has_many :options
  has_many :answers, through: :options
end

class Option
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end

class Answer
  has_many :options
  has_many :questions, through: :options
end
```

```
answers = [Answer.create(verbiage: 'Dailey'), Answer.create(verbiage: 'Once a week'), Answer.create(verbiage: 'Never')]
question = Question.create(verbiage: 'How often do you drink milk?', answers: answers)
question_2 = Question.create(verbiage: 'How often do you excercise?', answers: answers)
```

If the question is has a correct answer you can use a separate association which is a direct link to the the answers table:

```
class Question
  has_many :options
  has_many :answers, through: :options
  belongs_to :correct_answer, class_name: 'Answer'
end
```

Or you can add a boolean column to the `options` table if their can be multiple correct answers.

```
class Question
  has_many :options
  has_many :answers, through: :options
  has_many :correct_answers, through: :options, 
                             class_name: 'Answer',
                             -> { where(options: { correct: true }) }
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response @max, as I'm sure I'll need to refer to it in future applications/features, haha!  However for this particular instance, I only want a Question to have a single possible Answer and there won't be an ability to choose from multiple possible answers.  But cool example example/explanation that may serve someone else looking on here.